# jquery if an element is not clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there an efficient way in jQuery to detect if anything other than a specific element (and it's children) has been clicked ??

```
<body>
  <header></header>
  <p>stuff<p>
  <div class="floating-form">
    <form>more stuff</form>
  </div>
  <footer></footer>
</body>
```

Whats the best way to remove the floating form, by listening for a click on anything other than the floating form?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/152975/how-to-detect-a-click-outside-an-element

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Bind a click event listener to `$(document)` that removes *div.floating-form*.
2. Bind a click event to *div.floating-form* that **[stops event propogation](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/)**.

Answer (score 2):

The usual approach is to assign a click event handler to the specific element that does nothing other than stop event propagation.  Then assign another click handler to the entire page (i.e. to the document) that removes the element in question.  Clicks on the element won't propagate up to the document, so you'll get the functionality you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the event.target attribute to determine what element triggered the click.

http://api.jquery.com/event.target/

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).click(function() {
    //do something
});
$(".floating-form").click(function() {
    return false;
});
```